# Javascript for hover over one image to bring up another with description in a fixed place

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, function

Hey so I'm trying to create the JavaScript, functions and HTML coding for the website I am working on.I have 8 small images on the left hand side. A default large image on the right.  I want to make it so when I hover over each small image another different large image replaces the default large image on the right hand side with a description between the two.

LEFTSIDE

*small image1*
*small image2*
*small image3*
*small image4*
*small image5*
*small image6*
*small image7*
*small image8*

MIDDLE

```
                           *small image1 title*
                        *small image1 description*
```

RIGHTSIDE

```
                                                                *LARGE IMAGE*
```

Changes from default large image through 8 different large images (and descriptions, default image has no description) when you hover over small images. All is horizontal from each other.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: No one is just going to code you your website for free. Might have more luck at a job postings website.

Comment: Just a point in the right direction is all thats required. I don't expect people to do it for me but a start on what functions to use is a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the middle and rightside in a div, say it has the id rightdiv, then you can the load the content of this div with ajax. Onhover you can perform a new ajax call which will populate the rightdiv with the new content retrieved from the ajaxcall.

Take a look at a javascript libary like [jquery](http://docs.jquery.com). There you can find predefined functions for ajax calls and hover etc.